# Debug Safari on iOS 13+ on a Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, debugging, safari, remote-debugging

I'm trying to setup a test environment for debugging web sites in a Safari web browser so I can resolve certain CSS/JS issues that are present only on Safari.

I only have a Windows 10 PC to work with, so my question is what's the best way to achieve this?

I've found and read several posts regarding possible solutions/tools (e.g. `remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter`), but they don't seem to work with iOS 12+, so I'm stumped... any way to accomplish this?

Or can anyone suggest an alternative way to do this without buying a Mac?

Comment: I found the relevant issue https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/181 , but the solution presented does not for me.

Did you find a solution?

Comment: @savram yes, but you won't like it... my solution was to buy an old used Mac :)

Answer (score 9):

**2021 update:**

The creator of `remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter` here. I've built a replacement for RemoteDebug called [Inspect](http://inspect.dev), which packages everything together in a pleasant experience and enables easy iOS web debugging from Windows, macOS, and Linux, with a few extra features like screencasting and wifi debugging.

http://inspect.dev

Comment: Thank you, it looks promising. I'll try it out when I have a chance!

Comment: Having spent several hours trying to get all the download scoop/nvm/ios-webkits/etc components working and failing to get everything connected for most of that ... and then finally getting a very poor result via a cable into the ipad - I decided to try Inspect and found it to work first time and to be much more responsive. I can't stress how difficult and miserable Apple seems to allow their dev environment to be and how Inspect seems to resolve some of that. Now I've got to work out if I want to run this beyond the 30 day trial.

Comment: The windows installers fails with a javascript error...

Comment: For anyone looking to debug iOS with this, be advised it requires a paid subscription.